# mongodb remove document if array count zero after $pull in a single query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a requirement where my `comments` schema looks like the following

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "comments": [
    { "userId": "123", "comment": "nice" },
    { "userId": "124", "comment": "super"}
  ]
}
```

I would like to pull the elements based on the `userId` field.
I am doing the following query

```
comments.update({},{$pull:{comments:{userId:"123"}}})
```

My requirement is that if the array length became zero after the pull operator I need to remove the entire document for some reason.Is there a away to do this in a single query?

PS:I am using the mongodb driver.Not the mongoose

Comment: Not in a single "operation" but you can do it with [`.bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) and submit "two" operations at once. The reason it cannot be one is because you cannot perform multiple operations on the "same path" in the one update. Your requirement baffles me though, since actually removing has no benefit. It does not affect storage already allocated, and in fact it's somewhat dangerous to not have a field present at all where an array is generally expected.

Answer (score 4):

If I'm reading your question right, after the `$pull`, if the `comments` array is empty (zero length), then remove the document (`{ _id: '', comments: [] }`).

This should remove all documents where the `comments` array exists and is empty:

```
comments.remove({ comments: { $exists: true, $size: 0 } })
```

I had a similar requirement and used this (using `mongoose` though):

```
await Attributes.update({}, { $pull: { values: { id: { $in: valueIds } } } }, { multi: true })
await Attributes.remove({ values: { $exists: true, $size: 0 } })
```

Not sure if it's possible to do this in one operation or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use middlewares for this.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

Write a pre/post update method in mongodb to check your condition.